# I need a system for managing multiple bitcoin transactions using transaction information in my wallet

Tags: finance, accounting

I currently use Multibit, but am prepared to switch if necessary. What is the best way to organize my wallet so that I can access multiple 'send' and 'receive' transaction data to and from multiple customers?

Related, is there any commercial software available that can access wallet transaction data and analyze it to create simple financial reports such as transaction history for individual customers, filtered reports on all BTC receipts and withdrawals along with BTC values at (approximately, if necessary) the time of transaction execution, customer name along with his BTC address, etc.?

Or are there other potential suggestions or solutions out there?

PS Am not necessarily looking for freeware.

Comment: Are you looking for a point of sale application for a physical store or a web based application that will interact with your customers? I would guess that you may be in need of a custom application depending upon your particular requirements.

Comment: No, it is not to interact with customer-they already have mechanism to send and receive BTC from my gaming site.  Rather, I need an accounting capability that will use transaction info in my Wallets.